# sunspot solr how to search multiple models correctly? All examples online fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

How would one correctly search multiple models in SunSpot Solr?

**Profile model**

```
has_one :match

searchable do
  string        :country
  string        :state
  string        :city
end
```

**Match model**

```
belongs_to :profile

searchable do
  string :looking_for_education
  integer :age_from
  integer :age_to
end
```

**ProfilesController#Index**

```
def index
  
  @search = Sunspot.search Profile, Match do

    with(:country, params[:country])
    with(:state,   params[:state])      
    with(:looking_for_education, params[:looking_for_education]) <= from the 2nd model
  end

  @profiles = @search.results

end
```

This fails with:

```
 Using a with statement like 
  with(:age).between(params[:age_from]..params[:age_to])
 undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
```

Removing the
with(:age).between(params[:age_from]..params[:age_to]) line then it tries to

then it tries to load the

```
view app/views/educators/educator.html.haml
```

which does not exist ( im only using

```
/app/views/profiles/_profile.html.haml
```

to show profiles

## EDIT #1:

What are good opensource projects in ruby on rails that use sunspot and solr in a bit more advanced way to have a look at? Maybe I can find the answer there. Any answer in this direction will also be accepted the bounty if it yields in resulting this issue, thx!

Comment: could you plz show me the error in detail, I mean in which file , which line?

Comment: @Muntasim thanks for the comment, i updated post it was not very  clear sorry about that. Any idea why this happens and how to do correctly? thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method you've found for searching multiple models is correct. However, it appears that the meaning of your search is not what you intended. It looks as if you're trying to say:

> Give me all `Profile` records with these `country` and `state` values, **and** whose `Match` record has this `looking_for_education` value

Your search, however, says:

> Give me all records of type `Profile` **or** `Match` that have **all** of these `country`, `state` and `looking_for_education` values

Because neither `Profile` nor `Match` have all of these fields in their respective `searchable` blocks, no single record can match the conditions you specify.

If I'm correct about your intended behaviour above, then you need to include the profile's associated match information in the profile's `searchable` block, like so:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :match

  searchable do
    string(:country)
    string(:state)
    string(:city)
    string(:looking_for_education) { match.looking_for_education }
    integer(:age_from)             { match.age_from              }
    integer(:age_to)               { match.age_to                }
  end
end
```

Here, we've told Sunspot to index properties of the profile's match association as if they lived on the profile itself. In the respective blocks, we've told Sunspot how to populate these values when the profile is indexed.

This will allow you to write your search using only the `Profile` model:

```
def index
  @search = Sunspot.search Profile do
    with(:country, params[:country])
    with(:state,   params[:state])      
    with(:looking_for_education, params[:looking_for_education])
    with(:age).between(params[:age_from]..params[:age_to])
  end

  @profiles = @search.results
end
```

This search will return only `Profile` records, while still reflecting the properties of each profile's match association, because we stored them when the profile was indexed.

Note that this increases complexity when you index your models. If a `Match` record changes, its associated profile now needs to be reindexed to reflect those changes.

Comment: string        :looking_for_education { match.looking_for_education } is incorrect syntax

Answer (score 4):

This is what i  am doing when i have to search for multiple models

```
Sunspot.search [Model1, Model2] do
  ....
end
```

Comment: this fails for me still

Answer (score 4):

@moises-zaragoza answered correctly your question but you have more issues than you think with what you want to do.

**The first error:**

```
 Using a with statement like 
  with(:age).between(params[:age_from]..params[:age_to])
 undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass
```

Is most likely produced because params[:age_from] and/or params[:age_to] are nil. I can't assure it because you haven't shown the stacktrace. You can fix by filter only when they are present:
      with(:age).between(params[:age_from]..params[:age_to]) if params[:age_from].present? and params[:age_to].present?

**The second error**

Related to your views. I am assuming you are rendering a collection or object with one of the rails helper partial object helpers, without specifying the partial (again, without the code this is more of a good guess than anything else):

```
<%= render @results %>
```

or

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
  <%= render result %>
<% end %>
```

When Rails does not have a partial specified, it guesses the partial name depending on the object type. In this case, if your object is for example of class Educator, which might be a subclass of Profile, Rails will look for the partial 'educators/_educator.html.erb. Make sure you render the proper partial depending on the object type and this will ensure you render what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here the answer for search different model on matching string using `with`

```
searchable(:auto_index => AppConfig.solr.auto_index) do
  string :category_name, :stored => true
  text :content, :stored => true
  text :title
  string :company_id, :stored => true
  time :published_on
end

search do |q|
  if params[:keyword].present?
    q.fulltext params[:keyword] do
      fields(:deal_data)
    end
  end
  if (ids = params["company_id"]).present?
    ids = ids.split(",")
    q.with(:company_id,ids) #here company id formate should be ["***","***"]
  end
end
```