# Rails 4 and Sunspot: searching across several related models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot

This question has been asked several times before and answered but none of the suggestions seem to work in my case.

I have a User model and Micropost model

A user has many microposts, a micropost has one user.

I am trying to search across the user model and micropost model at the same time using Sunspot.

All I need is the correct syntax for indexing the models.

I tried this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchable do
 text    (:full_name)
 text    (:last_name)
 text    (:first_name)
 text    (:email)
 text    (:job_title)
 text    (:city)
 text    (:country)
 text    (:address)
 text    (:tag_list)
 text    (:content ) { micropost.content }
 end
end
```

Based on

[sunspot solr how to search multiple models correctly? All examples online fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300137/sunspot-solr-how-to-search-multiple-models-correctly-all-examples-online-fail)

but this doesn't work. All I need is to search the content attribute of the micropost above. So if a person searches for a user, they get a user, if they search for a specific phrase that occurs in a micropost.content, they get the micropost(s) with that phrase.

The documentation doesn't help on this as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Your **USER** model should be like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchable do
 text    (:full_name)
 text    (:last_name)
 text    (:first_name)
 text    (:email)
 text    (:job_title)
 text    (:city)
 text    (:country)
 text    (:address)
 text    (:tag_list)
 end
end
```

Your **MICROPOST** model should be like:

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
 searchable do
 text    (:content)
 end
end
```

Then, on your **search_controller.rb** file:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(User, Micropost) do |query|
             query.fulltext params[:quick_search]
          end
@results = @search.results
```

then for each result create a loop:

```
@results.each do |result|
   if result.is_a?(User)
     //do something with the result        
   end 
   if result.is_a?(Micropost)
     //do something with the result        
   end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error                                                                     "undefined method `model_name' for #<Sunspot::Search::StandardSearch:0x007fa64e187648>"

Comment: If you have existing data in DB make sure to run `rake sunspot:solr:reindex` for indexing. For new data the indexing will be done in a hook. @GhostRider, before `indexing` restart your server.